A circuit from TL431 datasheets that makes no sense
In the "Applications and Implementation" section of the Texas Instruments datasheet for TL431 there is this circuit named "Output Control of a Three-Terminal Fixed Regulator":

The same circuit appears in the ON Semiconductor datasheet for TL431:

The idea behind this circuit is that by adjusting R1 you can set the output voltage of a fixed voltage regulator IC to any value, which is determined by the given equations.
But I don't see how this circuit is supposed to work and it does not work when I simulate it.
Do I miss something here or they provide incorrect and unchecked information in their datasheets?

I feel that I need to clarify.
I know that this would work and it does.

But this does not work at all (changing R1 {almost} does not change the TL431 cathode voltage):

And this is with R1 set to 2k as @SimonFitch has suggested. The TL431 is shut completely off, no current goes through it:

The cathode voltage has changed but only because TL431 became non-conductive and as a result we have totally lost regulation through 7805.

Update #2
Thank you, guys, a LOT for help. It took me a while to read all the answers and comments.
As @SimonFitch has correctly pointed out, there were two (rather silly, I must admit) errors with my implementation.
Firstly, the minimum Vout for this circuit is 7.5V = 5V + the minimum Vka for TL431 (which is 2.5V). And that means that if R2 is 1k, then the minimum value for R1 must be 2k. I tried that, of course, before posting my question, and it did not work. Now we know why (see below).
Secondly, the supply voltage turned out to be too low. It turned out (at least in my simulations) that the dropout voltage for this circuit is not 2V, not 2.5V and not even 4V. It's about 5V. It depends on the load current. If the load resistor (R3) is 100 Ohm, then the dropout voltage is about 5.1V (resistors R4 and R5 are added only to show the currents, they are not needed for the circuit to function):

See how L7805 is out of regulation when the supply voltage is 12.5V, and the circuit suddenly starts working when the supply voltage is 12.6V.
I am aware that models used in simulations are limited and simulation results might differ (sometimes totally) form what you obtain in reality. My interest in this particular circuit was purely theoretical but I will try to build it and check that later on, or if anyone of you have already checked that (the dropout voltage value), it would be interesting to know.
Why the dropout voltage became so high is a total mystery to me. I would appreciate if anyone can explain that.
Now we know that the circuit works.
But I still do not understand how.
As some of you have asked in the comments, my "conceptual" problem with this circuit is that TL431 is essentially connected to a constant current source. TL431 is a shunt regulator, meaning it does not regulate voltage at its cathode pin (without an additional circuitry), it can only regulate current form its cathode to anode. And when you connect it to a constant current source there is not much that it can regulate.
I have simulated a test circuit to demonstrate that:

See how changing R1 value from 2k to 3k does not really change the cathode voltage of TL431.
Compare to how it works with L7805:

So, my question is (and actually was, as I explained in the comments): how does TL431 regulate its cathode voltage in the original circuit with L7805, if it is connected to a constant current source (the GND pin of L7805) and can only change its cathode to anode current?

Update #3
After doing some more testing, it turned out TL431 can regulate its cathode voltage even when connected to an (almost) constant current source.


Update #4
Still trying to better understand this circuit, I followed an advice of @MathKeepsMeBusy and performed a transient analysis of the circuit. Here the supply voltage was first set to 12V, then it was increased to 12.6V, then it was decreased to 9.5V, and then it was further decreased to 9V.


Well, I did not expect such results. As you can see, we've got a circuit with hysteresis, reminiscent of the Schmitt trigger. At 12V supply voltage TL431 remains in the non-conductive state. As soon as the supply voltage reaches 12.6V, TL431 switches into the conductive state, and it remains in that state even after the supply voltage is decreased to about 9.25V. If the supply voltage is decreased further, TL431 begins to turn off and goes into the non-conductive state at about 9.1V supply voltage.
The results also show (as far as we can trust circuit simulations) that in this circuit, as long as the GND pin of L7805 has enough current going through it, the dropout voltage for L7805 at this load current is about 1.6V, which is what we would normally expect.
I also performed a DC analysis of L7805 alone, and it seems that a voltage drop of about 5V (depends on the load current) with little to no GND pin current - is just an intrinsic property of this IC, that is it was not created by the original circuit in question.

So, I think I finally have understood this circuit. Thank you all guys for the help!

What about it makes no sense? It seems fairly clear to me. It's likely a lot of simulation models of fixed regulators won't work for this, as they likely make assumptions about how things will be connected and include internal references to node 0 (ground), assuming it's connected to the ground pin of the regulator.

I never use circuit with extra gain in control loop.

@Hearth It makes no sense because the voltage regulator IC maintains a constant voltage between "Out" and "Common" pins, but changing R1 does not change cathode voltage of the TL431 IC, and thus it does not change the circuit output voltage.

@Autistic Sometimes it works super neat.

Changing R1 does change the cathode of the TL431, though, because it changes the regulator's output (to maintain 2.5 V on the 431's feedback pin) and, as you noted, the regulator maintains a constant voltage between its output and common terminals.

@Hearth But TL431, being a shunt regulator, can only adjust cathode to anode current, it cannot adjust cathode voltage in this configuration. Try to simulate it and see it for yourself.

@ThomasAnderson not sure whether it’s the conceptual issue or the implementation that is the basis of your question. Anyway I wrote  an answer

@ThomasAnderson Sorry if the deleted comment sounded snippy.

@ThomasAnderson, the TL431 can maintain constant cathode voltage by adjusting the cathode to anode current. Why is this not possible according to you (from a conceptual point of view and not by simulation because there could be an issue in your simulation)

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany "not sure whether it’s the conceptual issue or the implementation that is the basis of your question" I am not sure myself. The circuit does not seem to work at all. I guess, there might be a problem with the circuit.

@sai "the TL431 can maintain constant cathode voltage by adjusting the cathode to anode current" It certainly can, and that is how it is commonly used as a shunt voltage regulator. But it cannot in this circuit. Just try connecting it to a constant current source and see if it does.

@ThomasAnderson, ofcourse it can regulate the voltage with a constant current source. I just don't see what your concern is.

@ThomasAnderson Which simulation software did you use? And please add that info to your original question.

@ThomasAnderson Did you try adding 0.1 uF capacitors to 7805 from IN to GND and from OUT to GND pins? And then at least a 0.1 uF to 1 uF between the regulated output and circuit ground? That could be the source of your problems as well.

@ThomasAnderson it doesn't matter for SE, but  you should consider phrasing such a question with an attitude showing that you accept that you might be the one that is wrong. The attitude "lol these guys don't know what they are doing" ... "Oh sorry I was wrong, but whatever, happens", which I strongly sense between the lines here, will (rightfully) rub many people the wrong way. Just a word of advice from a stranger, do with it what you want.

@ThomasAnderson I have explained to you the source of the high drop-out voltage problem. I don't know what you don't understand about it.

@MathKeepsMeBusy I appreciate your help, but your explanation basically is: when the GND pin does not float, then the dropout voltage is 2.5-ish V, when the GND pin floats, then the dropout voltage is 4-ish V, just live with that. I agree, that is an explanation. I was hoping (not insisting) for, maybe, a more technical one.

@ThomasAnderson You write "when the GND pin does not float, then the dropout voltage is 2.5-ish V". While that is true, ask yourself if there is any input voltage for the Simon Fitch circuit at which your simulator gives Vin-Vout is 2.5 V? Then ask yourself why. You might also ask yourself if there are two different input voltages such that Vin(1)-Vout(1) = Vin(2)-Vout(2). Again, you might ask yourself why. If the answers are not obvious to you, perhaps you can dig deeper.

@MathKeepsMeBusy Which circuit is the Simon Fitch circuit? What I meant, everybody expected the dropout voltage to be about 2.5V, while in fact it turned out to be 5.1V. It would be nice to know why. Digging deeper is what I do, with your help, guys.

@ThomasAnderson This is the circuit https://i.sstatic.net/mLllmSwD.png. I'm glad you want to dig deeper. So is there any input voltage that will make Vin-Vout 2.5 V? Why is that? I'm not an expert with your simulator, in that circuit, Vin-Vout = 5.103 V. What happens if Vin is 12.603 V. What is Vin-Vout then?

Also, I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you refer to "the drop-out voltage". However, if you are referring to the the minimum value of Vin-Vout, when power is available at Vout (say 7.5 V) then your statement "everybody expected the dropout voltage to be about 2.5V" is just wrong. I certainly didn't expect it. Nor should anyone have expected it who looked at your circuit simulations carefully.

@MathKeepsMeBusy Dropout voltage for L7805 alone is about 2.5V (depends on the load current). Dropout voltage for this circuit (the minimum Vin-Vout for the circuit to work) is about 5V (also depends on the load current). Maybe not everybody, but a lot of guys in their comments and in their answers wrote they expected it to be about 2.5V. Of course, simulations made it apparent, but they do not explain why it is so high. Hence the question.

@MathKeepsMeBusy "What happens if Vin is 12.603 V" - I have simulated that already: https://i.sstatic.net/51evTWRH.png Why are you asking that?

@ThomasAnderson I am asking questions to test your understanding of the circuit, and perhaps challenge that understanding. Can you explain why Vin-Vout is approximately the same for both Vin = 12 V and Vin=12.6 V? Do you have an idea what might happen if you do a time domain simulation of your circuit and raise the input voltage to 12.6 V and then lower it to 12 V?

@MathKeepsMeBusy "Can you explain why Vin-Vout is approximately the same for both Vin = 12 V and Vin=12.6 V?" - That I don't know. Why is it approximately the same?

@MathKeepsMeBusy "Do you have an idea what might happen if you do a time domain simulation of your circuit and raise the input voltage to 12.6 V and then lower it to 12 V?" - I did the simulations and put the results in my question. Please see if I got them right.

@ThomasAnderson That is great that you see the time simulations. Now you see that there are two stable operating points for a range of input voltages. I asked if you understood why the output at Vin=12 V was approx equal to output at Vin=12.6 to help you realize the two stable operating points. I don't have your simulator, but I chose those voltages guessing that they would have the same, or nearly the same, output voltage. Nothing special about that pair of input voltages. You can see now, that there are many other pairs. +1 for your effort at understanding!

With the additional schematics, it's clear you have violated the constraint
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{O(MIN)} &= V_{REF} + 5V \\ \\
&= 2.5V + 5V \\ \\
&= +7.5V
\end{aligned}
$$
This equation is written on the datasheet's schematic, figure 10-6. With \$R_1=500\Omega\$ and \$R_2=1k\Omega\$, it seems you are attempting to obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
 V_{OUT} &= V_{REF} \left( 1+\frac{R_1}{R_2} \right) \\ \\
&= 2.5 \left( 1+\frac{500}{1k} \right) \\ \\
&= +3.75V
\end{aligned}
$$
That's lower than the minimum possible of +7.5V.
The lowest value of R1 permissible here is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT(MIN)} &= V_{REF} \left( 1+\frac{R_1}{R_2} \right) \\ \\
7.5 &= 2.5 \left( 1+\frac{R_1}{R_2} \right) \\ \\
R_1 &= R_2 \left(\frac{7.5}{2.5}-1 \right) \\ \\
&= 2k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Perhaps you have the misapprehension that the GND connection of a fixed voltage regulator such as the 7805 is part of the power supply for the device. It isn't. It is merely a "reference potential", that the regulator is using to gauge whether its current output potential is too high, or too low, and adjust accordingly.
In fact the regulator's power supply is the potential difference \$V_{IN} - V_{OUT}\$, and by changing the potential of its GND pin (which I will call Q here), we are only altering the IC's perception of what "too high or too low" actually means:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The function of the regulator goes as follows: if the potential difference \$V_{OUT}-V_Q\$ exceeds 5V, then lower output potential \$V_{OUT}\$. If that potential difference falls below 5V, then raise \$V_{OUT}\$. The result is a system that settles in the equilibrium condition:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} - V_Q &= +5V \\ \\
V_{OUT} &= +5V + V_Q \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Above left I have connected Q to ground, setting \$V_Q = 0V\$, resulting in the condition:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= +5V + V_Q \\ \\
&= +5V + 0V \\ \\
&= + 5V
\end{aligned}
$$
That's the usual configuration for a fixed-voltage regulator such as the 7805, but there's nothing stopping you from using it as an adjustable one, by changing \$V_Q\$. That's what I've done in the right-hand circuit above, by introducing an offset to \$V_Q\$, raising it above ground by 2V: \$V_Q=0V + V_2 = +2V\$. To maintain the condition \$V_{OUT}-V_Q=5V\$, shown on VM3, output \$V_{OUT}\$ must also rise by 2V:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= +5V + V_Q \\ \\
&= +5V + 2V \\ \\
&= +7V
\end{aligned}
$$

We've established that the 7805 performs the function
$$ V_{OUT} = V_Q + 5V $$
Now let's plug in the TL431, to modulate \$V_Q\$. In the same way the 7805 wants to keep 5V between OUT and Q, the TL431 wants to keep 2.5V between its adjustment ADJ pin and its anode, shown on voltmeter VM3 here:

simulate this circuit
Note: the TL431 needs more than 1mA of cathode current to flow (taken from \$I_Q\$), but it just so happens that the 7805 GND pin sources significantly more than that, as I'll explain later, so the TL431 will function just fine.
Therefore, by KVL:
$$ V_{OUT} = 2.5V + V_{R1} $$
We calculate \$V_{R1}\$ using Ohm's law as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_P &= \frac{V_{OUT}}{R_1 + R_2} \\ \\
V_{R1} &= I_P R_1 \\ \\
&= V_{OUT}\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Combine them:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= 2.5 + V_{R1} \\ \\
V_{OUT} &= 2.5 + V_{OUT}\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} \\ \\
V_{OUT}\left(1 - \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}\right) &= 2.5 \\ \\
V_{OUT}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} &= 2.5 \\ \\
V_{OUT} &= 2.5 \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_2} \\ \\
&= 2.5 \left( 1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2} \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Stuff I wrote before I realised the 7805 was inside the feedback loop of the TL431
As food for thought, the main difference between a so-called "adjustable" regulator and a fixed-voltage one is its internal reference voltage. For the LM317, that reference is 1.25V, and you can actually use it as a fixed +1.25V regulator by tying its "ADJ" pin directly to ground:

simulate this circuit
This means that in principle you could use a fixed-voltage regulator as you would an adjustable one, with resistors to control the output voltage:

simulate this circuit
The 7805 tries to maintain 5V across R1 (see voltmeter VM2), in contrast to the adjustable LM317, which keeps 1.25V there. In practice, using a fixed-voltage regulator in this way doesn't work very well, because GND pin current is significant, as shown on ammeter AM1. That current messes up the R1/R2 potential divider voltage, causing a severe offset at the GND/ADJ pin. This problem goes away when you use a TL431 (or any low impedance voltage source) to set the potential of the GND/ADJ pin, since such a source will sink any amount of current, and still maintain a fixed, accurate and known potential there.
The LM317 works well using only a pair of resistors, because its ADJ pin current is small, under 100μA, which won't significantly upset the potential produced at the resistors' junction. The reason GND pin current for the 7805 is so large stems from the fact that a 7805 is really just an adjustable regulator with the output-setting resistor divider built-in:

simulate this circuit
This enables regulator IC designers to use the same internal circuitry, changing only R2 (also internal) to produce any output potential they require. Thus the 7805, 7809, 7812 etc. are all the same IC, with R2 trimmed to suit.
This doesn't change the fact that you can set the potential of the GND pin to anything you like, to alter \$V_{OUT}\$. Here I'll use zener diode D1 to raise GND pin potential by 5.1V, to obtain \$V_{OUT}\approx+10.1V\$:

simulate this circuit

With the TL431 in place, which is regulating based on the actual output \$V_{OUT}\$, it doesn't care what regulator U1 you employ. It will always apply whatever potential \$V_Q\$ is necessary to produce \$V_{OUT}\$ according to its own goal, that \$V_P=+2.5V\$. Some examples to illustrate:

simulate this circuit
Note: In the middle design, LM317 ADJ pin current is insufficient to operate the TL431. R4 is inserted to source more current for the TL431, about 10mA, and simultaneously satisfy the LM317's requirement that it must source at least 10mA to regulate properly.
The first and second designs (left and middle) employ different regulators, a 7805 maintaining 5V between OUT and GND, and an LM317 maintaining 1.25V between OUT and ADJ. In both cases, the TL431 doesn't care what they do, it will raise or lower Q potential to whatever is necessary to obtain \$V_P=+2.5V\$, which occurs only when \$V_{OUT} = 8.0V\$.
If further proof were needed, on the right I've completely removed the regulator, replacing it with a simple resistor. Now the TL431 is operating as a shunt regulator, all on its own, and it still obtains \$V_P=+2.5V\$ and \$V_{OUT} = 8.0V\$.
The use of the 7805 or LM317 provides these benefits:

High current output, that the TL431 alone is incapable of achieving.

Over-temperature cut-off protection


As far as those devices are concerned, they are still regulating, unaware that there's a TL431 in the outer control loop, and you might wonder why you'd use the TL431 at all. Since the TL431 is doing the real voltage regulation now, you obtain at least two extra benefits:

Better output voltage precision, since the TL431 specs are better (probably - check the datasheets) in this respect.

Lower temperature coefficient. A regulator's output tends to vary with temperature. The TL431 has a better temperature coefficient, and it isn't heating up nearly as much as the 7805/LM317 because it's not passing any load current.



Thank you for such a huge answer. The part about 7805 inner resistors is very educational. Did you use some kind of zener diode model instead of TL431 for your simulation? Also, why don't you take into consideration the TL431 reference (adjustment) pin current?

@ThomasAnderson Since you posted your schematics, it's clear what the problem is, and my answer went way beyond that, way too far. I've inserted the actual answer (given the new information) at the top.

@ThomasAnderson Yes, I used a regular zener to "pretend" to be the TL431, and I set its voltage to represent exactly what the TL431 would do under the same conditions. The question about the TL431 adjustment pin current is a very good one. There's obviously some current (I don't recall exactly how much), but it would affect the results. It's so small, though, I neglected it.

"The lowest value of R1 permissible here is ..." It does not work with 2k either. With 2k the TL431 just shuts completely off.

The TL431 adjustment pin current could be up to 10mA. Not so small. It is incorrect to use a regular zener instead of TL431. Can't you do a simulation with TL431?

@ThomasAnderson Not on circuitlab, no TL431 model. On the TL431 datasheet, reference input current is 4μA max. Try R1=3k, and bump up the 12V supply to 20V. Don't forget the 7805 drop-out voltage is a ridiculously high 2.5V.

+1. It is a common gotcha with the TL431 that you need at least 2.5 V across the "K" and "A" pins for it to work properly. Similar ICs exist that need only 1.25 V. Using these, the circuit could be designed for output voltages of V_REF,min = 1.25 V plus the fixed voltage of the 78xx IC. There is another common gotcha: The 78xx ICs use npn pass transistors and therefore need a fairly large voltage drop across "in" and "out" to work properly. With all these drawbacks, I prefer linear regulatos with a 431 and a npn pass transistor, or pnp, for LDOs (stability is an issue with the latter).

@ThomasAnderson also please measure 7805 GND pin current.

@SimonFitch " On the TL431 datasheet, reference input current is 4μA max" No, look in the table 6.1 Absolute Maximum Ratings - up to 10mA.

@ThomasAnderson When the TL431 pin potentials are all within spec, REF/ADJ pin current won't exceed 4μA. That figure of 10mA tells you what current would damage the device, not what current would flow during normal operation. I don't know how you would make 10mA flow; perhaps by applying a potential negative w.r.t. the anode, which is certainly outside the usual operating regime of the TL431. In this application, I expect less than 4μA REF/ADJ pin current.

@SimonFitch I have found the error, and yes, you are right. The supply voltage was too low. I increased it and the circuit worked. I still do not understand how TL431 regulates here. Will need to give it some thought later. I have to go now. Will not be available for some hours. Thank you guys for the help.

@zebonaut In all my career, I have never once found this application of 78xx + precision voltage reference to be of any use. In a pinch I'd always go with the adjustable + two resistors. If I need the precision and tempco of the TL431, but the power of a TO220 thing, I still wouldn't use a 78xx, always an LM317 (or similar) with the TL431.

@ThomasAnderson I've added a section at the end to explain why the TL431 is now in charge of regulating, in spite of the 7805 above it, and why you'd use this design at all.

The 78xx + 431 has some uses although it needs to be compensated to work properly. It is basically a cheap solution for low-spec applications and is overheat- and short-protected. If lowest cost consumer market is not the target, then using just about any other linear regulator that can do the job by itself will be a more sensible choice.

@SimonFitch Did you read my test results for TL431 and LM7805 in my answer? I have placed them near the top. I will also build this circuit and test it to see at which voltage it starts working properly. Do you know which simulation software was used by the questioner (Thomas Anderson)?

@EdinFifić Yes, I read your tests, and no, I don't know what simulator OP used. I am confident that the circuit works fine as long as supply far exceeds 7.5V+dropout, to ensure GND pin current well above 1mA, and as long as R1>2kΩ.

@SimonFitch Thank you again for such a detailed answer. I wonder if your example with LM317 and TL431 will actually work in real life, since the LM317 ADJ pin current is only about 50uA, not enough for TL431 to function. But I simulated it in Micro-Cap, with an actual TL431 model, and in simulation it works, despite that fact. Which is kind of strange.

@SimonFitch By the way, when you describe the internal resistors in a fixed voltage regulator, did you just guess their values, or you have some intel? Because the current through the ground pin of 7805 (about 5mA) seems to be less than what those resistors would set.

@SimonFitch I have updated my question to better explain what my problem with the circuit is. If it is not too much trouble, could you please explain that last bit?

@ThomasAnderson As you noted, the LM317 ADJ pin current is too small for the TL431, so you would add some resistance between cathode and positive supply to source extra current. I guessed values for the 7805 internal resistor divider. You can infer them from GND pin current, with two assumptions: input bias current for the internal error amplifier is negligible, and internal reference is 1.25V, neither of which I can be sure. For example, if you measure 5mA, and assume $V_{REF}=1.25V$, that implies total resistance of $\frac{5V}{5mA}=1k\Omega$ and $\frac{R_1}{R_2}=\frac{1.25V}{3.75V}$

It totally makes sense if you know enough details about both ICs.
Let me give you a solid word of advice: don't rely 100% on simulations, as they sometimes give you unrealistic results!
Have you ACTUALLY BUILT this simple circuit? I know that I will.
(And I just DID! Actually, I have tested BOTH the 7805 and 431 ICs. READ BELOW!)
After some good questions you have posed in the comments to other answers, I was curious myself as to whether and how it would work.
First, I tested the TL431 IC.
Its cathode to anode current was almost constant at less than 1 uA (around 0.5 to 0.7 uA) when applying from about 1 V to 20 V across them while the reference pin was left floating (disconnected).
Shorting the reference pin to the anode pin made the cathode (the whole IC) current drop to ZERO (I couldn't measure below 0.01 uA or 10 nA with my instrument, so it was definitely less than 10 nA or practically zero).
All of this means that the TL431 IC provides no connection to ground for the LM7805 GND pin in your circuit when the TL431 REF pin is below +2.5V relative to its anode pin, proving your assumption right about the 7805 GND being left floating until the TL431 REF pin reaches about +2.5V.
Next, I tested the LM7805 for its GND pin current (quiescent current) and its output voltage with its GND pin floating, to see whether it would conduct current and provide voltage on its OUT pin in that case.
(NOTE: I tried testing it without any capacitors and its output voltage wasn't correct and stable until I used a 10 nF capacitor between its IN and GND pins. So, any time 78xx regulators are used as linear voltage regulators, AT LEAST 10 nF capacitors at their inputs and outputs should be used, but going with the recommended 100 nF and 1 uF is definitely better.)
My measurements showed that the GND pin current is below 1mA until about 5.4 V is applied, at which moment it rises quickly to about 3 to 4 mA, and stabilizes around or above 5 mA as the IN voltage is raised to 20V.
The most important part was that with the GND left floating, the LM7805 let the current flow through it practically freely, with a voltage drop of about 4 V between its IN and OUT pins, starting from just below 4 V and all the way up to 11 V beyond which I didn't bother testing because I had a 2W/10Ω resistor as a load and the current reached 700 mA (at 7 V across it, that was almost 5 W of power dissipation).
Tying the GND pin to the IN pin made the current even larger, while reducing the voltage drop across the IN and OUT pins down to 3 V or less.
The conclusion in the end is that the circuit with LM7805 and TL431 suggested in the datasheets would actually work because the 7805 itself will almost freely pass the current and allow the voltage on its output to rise until it reaches the voltage set by the resistive voltage divider, at which point the 431 starts providing a virtual ground to the 7805 which stabilizes its output voltage.
(The text below is regarding your original question and its schematics)
You were probably assuming that the 431 cathode can go almost to zero, but the minimum working voltage for the cathode is 2.0V, which some datasheets don't inform you about.
Here is your wrong schematic with my notes on it:

If you use resistor divider values assuming you can get less than 7.0V at the output, you will set the 431 outside of its operating area and the results will be unpredictable.
Now on to the explanation of how it all works...
As you likely know most of what I will tell you, feel free to skip to the last schematic and enjoy simulating it!
Its behavior is very similar to the real 431.
You have probably seen a fixed linear voltage regulator with a Zener diode added to it to increase its output voltage by the amount of the Zener voltage, like the one below:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The 7805 or any 78xx voltage regulator has its GND pin current going anywhere from 3 to 10mA, the current typically doesn't change much so adding a Zener diode which requires a few mA for its Zener voltage makes it a good combination.
The 431 shunt voltage regulator works much like a Zener diode, in that it maintains a stable voltage across its Anode and Cathode pins, but that voltage is adjustable with its Reference pin.
The working range of currents through the 431 is from 1mA to 100mA, so as long as the the current through the 431 remains within that range, the voltage across its Anode and Cathode pins remains well regulated and very stable.
The 431 works by maintaining 2.5V on its Reference pin, and passing more current between Anode and Cathode if the voltage on its Reference pin starts going above 2.5V.
The opposite happens if voltage on the R pin starts going below 2.5V; the 431 reduces the current between its A and C pins, similar to the Zener diode.
The minimum voltage that can be set is the Reference pin voltage of 2.5V, and this is achieved by simply shorting the Reference and Cathode pins.
Any other voltages (up to 30V) can be achieved by placing a voltage divider across the regulated voltage and sending the divided voltage to the Reference pin.
For example, if you want to double the 2.5V and get 5V across the A and C pins of the 431, you simply place two equal value resistors across the regulated voltage and connect the halved voltage between them to the R pin.
Other values are achieved using various resistance combinations or placing a potentiometer across or a variable resistor on the upper leg with a fixed resistor on the lower leg.
Since the R pin needs very little current, those resistances can be large and their load on the output is negligible.
Below is a schematic with 7805 and transistor-zener combination (which simulates the 431 IC) with indicated voltages and current to give you an idea.
Feel free to experiment with values of resistors or to even make a short between the base and the collector pins which represent reference and cathode pins on the 431 (just click on "simulate this circuit" under the schematic).

simulate this circuit

"The most important part was that with the GND left floating, the 7805 let the current flow through it practically freely, with a voltage drop of about 4 V between its IN and OUT pins," Does that mean the input needs to be 4 V above desired output for reliable operation?

@MathKeepsMeBusy No, it means that there will be about a 4 V voltage drop across 7805 when its GND pin is left floating (i.e. disconnected). But if the GND pin is not floating, the input needs to be only (a minimum of) about 2 V above the output voltage to maintain regulation.

If Vin is not at least 4V above the desired Vout, what prevents the circuit from arriving at a state where Vout is insufficient to turn on the TL431, as in the simulation by the OP ( https://i.sstatic.net/mLllmSwD.png ) ? I would give you +2 for your experiments.

@MathKeepsMeBusy Can you check your question and re-phrase it? It doesn't make much sense as it stands now, at least not the first sentence. Anyway, if you're asking why that simulation doesn't work (and it should), I can think of 3 possible reasons: 1) difference between 431 ICs (I doubt it); 2) lack of capacitors, IN to GND and OUT to GND pins on 7805, or at least one at the input (between IN and GND of 7805); 3) the 431 IC model is lacking in his simulation software. Speaking of which, DO YOU KNOW WHICH SIMULATION SOFTWARE did he use?

The reason why the simulation doesn't work is because of the following cycle of causes. TL431 ref pin voltage too low -> TL431 cathode current essentially 0 -> 7805 ground pin current essentially 0 -> 7805 Vout voltage too low -> Voltage divider input voltage too low -> TL431 ref pin voltage too low. This cycle of causes provides operation point where neither the TL431 nor the 7805 is operating as desired. Raising the 7805 Vin voltage 4 V above desired Vout breaks that cycle by raising the 7805 Vout so that TL431 ref voltage is sufficient etc.

@MathKeepsMeBusy That was a good, exact description of how it doesn't work until it does. My question remains, what was the simulation software used by the questioner?

I assume some version of Spice, such as PSpice. But the OP is the only one who knows.

@EdinFific I am using Micro-Cap 12 for circuit simulations.

@EdinFific Those are great experiments that you have done! I have updated my question. If you have not yet disassembled your test circuit, could you please verify the dropout voltage value? I am a tad skeptical myself about the validity of the simulation results. It would be great if they are confirmed or disproved by a real practice.

@EdinFific "The 431 shunt voltage regulator works much like a Zener diode, in that it maintains a stable voltage across its Anode and Cathode pins, but that voltage is adjustable with its Reference pin." - I happen to disagree with that notion. I think that TL431 can only regulate its cathode to anode current, and cannot maintain a stable voltage at its cathode, without an additional circuitry.

The 7805 regulator has an almost constant current of a few mA flowing from the GND pin in normal operation. It regulates its output voltage to GND plus 5V. That is why a simple zener (or forward-biased diodes) can be used to increase the output voltage.
However simulation shows possible stability issues depending on the load.
If you close the loop around the TL431 only and put a 1uF cap from GND pin to ground, it behaves much better.

The TL431 has an equivalent circuit like this, from the datasheet :

When the voltage at the REF input of the TL431 increases past about 2.5V the transistor will pull down the "Cathode" pin, provided the current it sees is between about 1mA and 100mA. It also needs some voltage across it, 2.5V or so, to power itself including the internal reference. The 7805 provides about 3.5mA, close to ideal. If pulling down the Cathode results in the voltage at the REF input dropping then the loop may be closed. The simplest way to to connect Cathode and reference, or to add a voltage divider but there are other possibilities.
Since the 7805 is regulating its output to 5V above GND, the output voltage will increase or decrease depending on what the TL431 does. The TL431 RF input is "measuring" a set fraction of the 7805 output voltage, so the whole thing works as a regulator. Since the 7805 needs 2 or 3V and the TL431 2.5V, the minimum output voltage will be 7.5V and the minimum input voltage around 10V for 7.5V out, depending on current.
That's the theory and it does work under some conditions, but it's not stable and I don't recommend it as shown.
The TL431 is actually a very versatile (and affordable) part and can do far more that just act as a simple shunt regulator- an op-amp and a semi-precision voltage reference in one package.
Incidentally, one can drive the REF pin of a 7805 with an op-amp output, which can come in handy in some applications.

I just want you to know that I appreciate very much when people are trying to help, regardless of the result. I don't quite understand what you mean by "If you close the loop around the TL431 only". If you mean connecting R1 to the TL431 cathode, then I have already tried that and that circuit did work. However that is a completely different circuit and my question was why the circuit from the datasheets does not work.

I am aware about other means to increase the output voltage of a linear voltage regulator IC, like using zener diodes, regular diodes or a voltage divider. The problem with the circuit from the datasheets is that R1 does not seem to set the TL431 cathode voltage.

I found it to work in simulation with some loads (including no load) however the stability even when it didn’t oscillate was poor. I would include the results but it is not possible atm.

I have updated my question. We finally found what the error was, but I still do not understand how the circuit works.

In this circuit
 the voltage for the TL431 control line comes through a voltage divider from the L7805's ground pin. In that circuit, provided the input pin of the L7805 is at least 7.5 + 3.75 = 11.25 V, the ground pin will always have sufficient voltage to supply the ref pin of the TL431 with its required reference voltage.
In this next circuit, on the other hand, the reference pin of the TL431 is supplied by a voltage divider from the output pin of the L7805.

Depending on the output voltage of the L7805, there may or may not be sufficient voltage on the reference pin of the TL431 to make the TL431 conduct. If the TL431 is not conducting, the ground pin of the 7805 will be floating. If the ground pin of the 7805 is floating, the 7805 will not regulate properly. That is, there are theoretically at least, two stable states of this circuit. One with insufficient output voltage to cause proper voltage regulation, and one with sufficient output voltage to cause proper voltage regulation.
It may be, that in practice, the circuit always finds the "working" stable state, even though simulators might find either one.
@Edin Fifić has performed some experiments with the 7805 and has found that

with the GND left floating, the 7805 let the current flow through it practically freely, with a voltage drop of about 4 V between its IN and OUT pins,

If that is the case, then if the input voltage is at least 4 V above the desired output voltage, the output voltage of the 7805 will be sufficient to give the TL431 its required voltage on the ref pin for the feedback loop to regulate properly.
However, it is also conceivable that the voltage drop across a 7805 with no ground depends on the impedance of the load. Let's call whatever that voltage is, \$V_{drop}\$
If the input voltage does not satisfy
$$V_{in} \ge V_{out}+V_{drop}$$
then the circuit may not enter regulation reliably. Instead, it may enter a state where the ref pin of the TL431 is too low, so that the TL431 doesn't draw current from the 7805's ground pin, so the 7805 doesn't regulate properly, so the 7805's output voltage is low, so the TL431's ref pin's voltage is low, and round and round. It may especially not leave this state if the output has a capacitor to ground which will tend to suppress transients in the output voltage during startup that might bring the circuit into its proper working state.
My vote is that the circuit given in the OnSemi TL431 datasheet, i.e. this:

has an unnoted requirement, i.e.
$$V_{in} \ge V_{out}+ V_{drop}$$
for reliable operation, where \$V_{drop}\$ is the voltage difference the 7805's IN and OUT pins, when the GND pin is floating, and the OUT pin is connected to some load. The value of \$V_{drop}\$ may depend upon the impedance of the load.

Is the 7805 specified to conduct current from the source to the output when the "ground pin" potential is essentially the same as the input?  I know some regulators are deliberately designed not to conduct in such a situation, to prevent a failed ground connection from causing the input to pass through to the output.

I have ACTUALLY done some measurements now, and you can see the results in my answer. Basically, the 7805 WILL fully conduct to its output, with a voltage drop of about 4 V, starting from around 4 V and up. Tying its GND pin to its INPUT pin will make it even worse, conducting even more current with a voltage drop across IN and OUT pins being around 3 V.

My answer with the results of my tests is now complete. Check it out and let me know.

@MathKeepsMeBusy "has an unnoted requirement, i.e. ..." - more or less, the exact value seems to depend on the load current. I am getting 5.1V in simulations with a 100 Ohm load. Can you explain why it is so high?

@ThomasAnderson as noted in answer, there can be a stable state where the TL431's ref pin is below 2.5 V, it is not conducting, so the 7805 has no ground current, so it's output is low, so the TL431's ref pin is below 2.5 V, and round again. However, even if the ground pin of the 7805 has no current, the voltage from Vin to Vout will only get so large before Vout starts to follow along below Vin's voltage. When that happens, the system will move to a new state with both regulators on. Edin Fific measured that voltage to be 4 volts between Vin and Vout. That's where the 4 volts comes from.

@MathKeepsMeBusy "In that circuit, provided the input pin of the L7805 is at least 7.5 + 3.75 = 11.25 V, the ground pin will always have sufficient voltage to supply the ref pin of the TL431 with its required reference voltage." - That seems to depend on the load. With a 100 Ohm load I found this circuit would work down to about 10.4V supply voltage (at least in a simulation), since the dropout voltage for L7805 is less than 2.5V at low currents.

@ThomasAnderson Yes, you are right that that circuit works at input voltages below 11.25 V. But I wrote that "If the 7805 has at least 11.25 V, then the ground pin will have sufficient voltage..." That doesn't preclude the circuit from working at input voltages less than 11.25 V.

Basic idea
Believing that every specific circuit solution is based on some fundamental idea, I set out to find what that idea is here. Thus, I came to the conclusion that it is quite simple: in a fixed voltage regulator, we connect an additional external reference voltage source in series with the existing internal one. In this way, we can modify its stabilization voltage as we want.
Implementation
Let's trace how this idea can be implemented in classic transistor and op-amp circuit solutions, and thus understand it better. I propose we do this in a few steps, illustrating each with the three possible implementations - 7805, transistor, and op-amp.
Follower voltage regulator
Standalone 7805 voltage regulator
In essence, the regulator continuously monitors the voltage difference between its OUT and GND terminals. If this voltage deviates from the internal reference value (5 V in this case), the regulator adjusts its output voltage (referenced to the circuit ground) accordingly to maintain a constant 5 V output. I have connected a voltmeter with internal resistance of 1 kΩ as a load to visualize the output voltage.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Emitter follower
Similarly, an emitter follower with a constant input (base) voltage Vref adjusts its output (emitter) voltage VRL to maintain it (approximately) equal to Vref. To compensate for Vbe, I have increased Vref to 5.7 V.

simulate this circuit
Op-amp follower
An op-amp can act as a perfect voltage follower with constant input voltage Vref = 5 V. In voltage regulators, the amplifier drives a pass transistor which I have omitted here for simplicity (you can imagine it is inside the amplifier).

simulate this circuit
Amplifying voltage regulator
Our task now is to modify this 5 V regulator to produce a higher voltage, specifically 10 V.
7805 amplifying voltage regulator
Following the basic idea formulated in the beginning, we can add a R2/(R1 + R2)  part of the output voltage to 7805 internal reference voltage. Thus we make it increase R1/(R1 + R2) times its output voltage.

simulate this circuit
Op-amp non-inverting amplifier
This resembles the classic op-amp non-inverting configuration where an R1/(R1 + R2) part of the output voltage is compared with the reference voltage. As a result, the output voltage increases (R1 + R2)/R1 times.

simulate this circuit
"Lifted" voltage regulator
Simply put, to increase the stabilization voltage, we add another voltage source in series to the reference voltage source in each version below (the fragment bordered in red is the "lifted" circuit):
7805 "lifted" voltage regulator

simulate this circuit
"Lifted" emitter follower
Note that Vref is "floating"...

simulate this circuit
"Lifted" op-amp follower
... and here, too.

simulate this circuit
"Lifted" op-amp non-inverting amplifier
The preceding three versions are explicit, however, this one presents a somewhat counterintuitive notion that the additional source Vlift implies the introduction of a common-mode voltage.

simulate this circuit
"Lifting"  shunt voltage regulator
We can replace the conceptual voltage source with a Zener diode or TL431.

simulate this circuit
"Lifting" voltage divider
It becomes most interesting when an amplifying voltage regulator with an embedded voltage divider is "lifted" by another voltage divider, as is actually the case with 7805. We can illustrate it with the op-amp circuit in Schematic 3.4.

simulate this circuit
"Lowered" voltage regulator
Now, an interesting question arises: Since we can "raise" the voltage regulator with a positive voltage, can't we "lower" it with a negative voltage? If so, this would enable us to stabilize a voltage lower than its nominal.
7805 "lowered" voltage regulator
It turns out that we can (at least that is what CircuitLab thinks).

simulate this circuit
"Lowered" op-amp non-inverting amplifier
Let's illustrate this trick with the analogous op-amp circuit.

simulate this circuit

A very interesting and educational take on the topic. Don't you think a reversed polarity of "TL431" in 3.5 would work even better?

@Thomas Anderson, thanks for the feedback. I have modeled TL431 in this conceptual circuit through a forward-biased "ideal" diode with VF = 5V. It represents a 5V backward-biased Zener diode or 5V TL431 or any 5V voltage stabilizer.

Why don't you guys use normal circuit simulators instead of this limited CircuitLab? Is it because you don't have computers and write from your phones?

@Thomas Anderson, For my purposes (unveiling fundamental circuit ideas), CircuitLab is very suitable as an auxiliary tool. I use my imagination and accumulated experience as the primary 'simulator'. Unfortunately, CircuitLab doesn't work on my phone; there, I only write text, while I create schematics on my computer. I use Google Drive to connect the two. I also have to make a backup in Google Docs because I often lose my work when the phone's browser (Chrome) refreshes. The Samsung browser does this less often, so I often have to transfer between the two...

... All of these are just technical issues; the main thing for me is understanding circuit ideas and explaining them.

The circuit makes sense to me. The schematic may not be complete if compensation components are needed to stabilize the the combination of feedback loops from each IC, but it is complete from a DC point of view.
The TL431 circuit will adjust cathode current to regulate the ADJ pin to it's 2.5V reference
The MC7805 circuit will maintain a 5V difference between it's OUT and COMMON pins, given sufficient headroom from VIN.
The TL431 feedback loop is the outer loop, the MC7805 loop is the inner feedback loop.  The vendor schematics do not show any components added for stability - That might be a reason the simulation does not work, @Hearth 's response about how simulation models may not work when combined is really relevant.   If the MC7805 model does not accurately model how  VOUT-COMMON varies with I(COMMON), the two models may well not simulate together.
Conceptually, it might help to think of the MC7805 as a BJT in an emitter follower configuration with a 5V Vbe and go from there.  The function of the resistor from the BJT base to V+ is provided by the internal MC7805 circuit.

You are mistaken to think that the voltage regulator IC works like a BJT. It does not. TL431 cannot adjust cathode current in this circuit. The common pin of the voltage regulator IC works as an about constant current source.

If some manufacturer's 7805 would only pass current to the output pin if sufficient current were drawn from it to pull the ground pin 0.7 volts or more below the input, the circuit could reach an equilibrium state where the ground pin of the 7805 would set very slightly below the input.  In that scenario the voltage on the ref pin of the TL431 would never be high enough to pull down the ground pin on the 7805 enough to make it start conducting.

@supercat I totally do not understand what you mean by that. Any chance you can explain it?

I have been working with TL432 for my circuit. Well it is basically a shunt regulator. You can have the application diagram from TI. (note: TL431 and TL432 are basically same).
Its reference voltage is 2.5 V.  By adjusting the resistor we can vary the output voltage. But the reference should be 2.5 V. For example in my circuit  Vin = 12 V   Vref = 2.5 V  Vout = 0.7 V to 1 V. Here is my circuit schematic diagram.
I think you can get an idea how it works.



Basically the output is pulled up to +12 V. When TL431 gets enough ref it pulls the output voltage to low.
This is the working.
Don't place all your trust in the formula.

Good luck with your circuit! Looks neat!

What question does this answer?

Tip: use 2 x  for paragraph break in markdown syntax. The double-space at the end of a line forces a line break but it doesn't open a paragraph gap.

A 7805 keeps the output a fixed 5V above the GND pin. That’s the trick. Some simulation models don’t.
So to turn a 7805 into a higher output voltage regulator, it just takes raising GND above 0V. Say if you put a 1.5V battery in series with the GND pin, the output will be 6.5V. Try it. It works a treat - just don’t do it too long since the GND pin current tries to recharge the battery.
The TL431 in those circuits adjusts the potential of the 7805s GND pin to obtain the desired output voltage. The accuracy and drift of 7805 play no role in performance. It is the voltage reference in the 431 and the external feedback resistors that determine the voltage.

"The TL431 in those circuits adjusts the potential of the 7805s GND pin to obtain the desired output voltage" Unfortunately, it does not. At least not through changing the value of R1. Why do you guys write answers without testing it first or giving it some thought?

@ThomasAnderson Feel free to check my answer...

@ThomasAnderson It sure does. Five minutes with a breadboard and you get a circuit which starts up reliably and provides rock solid regulation (for values of "rock solid" applicable to these 70's era ICs, of course). That it does not work in simulation for you is clearly a limitation of the models.

@ThomasAnderson Why do you guys write answers without testing it first or giving it some thought? I have physically put that circuit together several times over the years. As long as the Nature still works the same, and the FABs still supply the parts, I stand by my answer :) You should be able to get realistic results by implementing the 431 in the simulator, based on the schematic in the datasheet. See e.g. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/655273/10810 , although CircuitLab is not great and it works only when tweaked just so.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica My bad, the circuit does work. But I still don't understand how (silly me).
